# minimax inequality

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Given any function $\varphi : X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ it holds that

$$\max_{y}\min_x \varphi(x,y) \le \min_y\max_y \varphi(x,y).$$

The proof I'm trying to read states the following thing: 1)the above inequality can be proven by considering that
$$For \,\, all \,\, x,y \qquad \min_x \varphi(x,y) \le \max_y \varphi(x,y)$$

(Why is this true?)

2. Then I can take $\max_y$ on left-hand side since the above ineq is true for all $y$ values, getting:

$$\max_y\min_x \varphi(x,y) \le \max_y \varphi(x,y)$$

3)Finally I can take the $\min_x$ on the 'inner' part of the equality, getting
$$\max_y\min_x \varphi(x,y) \le \max_y (\min_x)\varphi(x,y)$$

Are these steps correct? Also why is the first inequality (1) true? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your statement isn't well stated. Maybe you want prove the following?: $\max_\limits {y}\min_\limits x \varphi(x,y) \le \min_\limits x\max_\limits y \varphi(x,y)$ (note that on the RHS you have taken the minimum on $y$ after taking the maximum on $y$ too, which doesn't make much sense).

For the first part, note that for all $x,y$ we have $\min_\limits x \varphi(x,y) \le\varphi(x,y)$ and $\varphi(x,y) \le \max_\limits y \varphi(x,y)$, so for all $x,y$ we have $\min_\limits x \varphi(x,y) \le \max_\limits y \varphi(x,y)$.

The second step seems ok, but it should be pointed out that the inequality holds for all $x$.

The third step is just taking minimum on $x$, not on the inner part or anything, it's just like you did with the maximum in the second step.

Comment: It is also true that $\min_y \varphi(x,y) \le \max_x \varphi(x,y)$ right?

Comment: Yes, by the same logic we would have another inequality: $\max_\limits {x}\min_\limits y \varphi(x,y) \le \min_\limits y\max_\limits x \varphi(x,y)$

Comment: you are right, I messed it up.in (3) step, taking the minimum on $x$ would result in $(\min_x) \max_y \min_x \varphi(x,y) \le \min_x \max_y \varphi(x,y)$ but of course on the left hand side I've already taken the minimum on $x$ and hence the expression is redundant. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, it's like taking the minimum on one number, it doesn't change it.